# Which one is correct: "act as intermediary" or "act as an intermediary"?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

Can you please tell me which one is correct: *act as intermediary* or *act as an intermediary*? For example:

> The company acts as (**an**) intermediary between the customer and the contractor.

In a book called *English Phrasal Verbs in Use* by Micheal McKarthy and Felicity O'Dell they omitted *a* on the following sentence.

> One of the robbers acked as lookout while others robbed the bank.

Is the omissio of *a* typo there or is it optional in this type of sentences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A word denoting a job or role is often used without an article after *as* (meaning "taking or performing the job or role").

The article may be used but is not required.

For example, the NOW corpus has 50 instances of "act as intermediary", against 1482 of "act as an intermediary".

Answer (score 1):

In both cases (assuming you mean the 'a' could come before 'lookout'), the article is optional.